# How to pass object in method to call service API in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have defined a method defined in AppService file, Signature of method is `public PagedResultDto<FetchData> GetSearchData(FetchDataInput searchInput)`. I'm calling this method from Angular code, but `service-proxoes.ts` file has generated method in which I need to pass all the parameters one by one.

```
public class FetchDataInput: PagedAndSortedInputDto, IShouldNormalize
{
    public int DataLevel { get; set; }
    public int DataType { get; set; }
    public string DataCode { get; set; }
    public string DescLong { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public string DataParent { get; set; }

    public void Normalize()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sorting))
        {
            Sorting = "DataCode";
        }
    }

}
```

Service-Proxies.ts file:

```
    getSearchData(dataLevel: number, dataType: number, dataCode: string, descLong: string, languageCode: string, dataParent: string, sorting: string, maxResultCount: number, skipCount: number): Observable<PagedResultDtoOfFetchData> {
```

So I have to call the `getSearchData` method by the following way.

```
this._dataService.getSearchData(AppConsts.dataLevelType, undefined, undefined,
        undefined, this.currentLanguage.name, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined).subscribe((result) => {
           //result.items;
        });
```

So I have to pass all the parameters, but if let's say there are 100 parameters, it will be error prone and not good programming style. So it has to take a class object that's it. So is there any way to do the this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a object to store those parametter like this:

```
public class FetchDataInput: PagedAndSortedInputDto, IShouldNormalize
{
    public SearchModel searchModel{get; set;}

    public void Normalize()
    {           
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sorting))
        {
            Sorting = "DataCode";
        }
    }

}

public class SearchModel
{
        public int DataLevel { get; set; }
        public int DataType { get; set; }
        public string DataCode { get; set; }
        public string DescLong { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string DataParent { get; set; }
}
```

...And in the getSearchData, tried to serialize the model and pass it to your api:

```
_$SearchModelForm= _modalManager.getModal().find('form[name=SearchForm]');
var searchModel = _$SearchModelForm.serializeFormToObject();
this._dataService.getSearchData(searchModel);
```